# How to parse dict type in pandas column into columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1],
        "d": [
                {
                "status": {"version": "1.0.0"},
                "property": [
                    {
                        "identifier": {"Id": 159156651},
                        "area": {"loctype": "VIEW - NONE"},
                        "address": {"country": "US"},
                        "summary": {
                            "absenteeInd": "ABSENTEE(MAIL AND SITUS NOT =)",
                            "propclass": "Industrial",
                        },
                        "utilities": {"energyType": "YES"},
                        "building": {
                            "size": {"bldgsize": 159183, "grosssize": 159182},
                            "rooms": {},
                            "interior": {},
                            "construction": {"constructiontype": "STEEL"},
                            "parking": {},
                            "summary": {
                                "bldgsNum": 101,
                                "bldgType": "COMMERCIAL",
                                "levels": 1,
                                "quality": "EXCELLENT",
                                "storyDesc": "COMMERCIAL",
                                "unitsCount": "144",
                            },
                        },
                        "vintage": {"lastModified": "2021-11-23"},
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
)
```

I'd like to parse certain `keys` from the dictionary and assign them to new columns.

When I attempt to transform the `dict` to `str` and parse the contents, I get the following error:

```
df['d'].str['property'].str['building']
NaN
```

Comment: you forgot a `str[0]`: `df['d'].str['property'].str[0].str['building']`, but honestly, use a loop here, not the `str` accessor.

Comment: @mozway can you share how to implement a loop or a function to parse dicts?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a recursive helper function:

```py
def flatten(data, new_data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                flatten(item, new_data)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            flatten(value, new_data)
        if isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, int):
            new_data[key] = value
    return new_data
```

So that all the values are easily accessible:

```py
print(flatten(df["d"][0], {}))

# Output
{'version': '1.0.0',
 'Id': 159156651,
 'loctype': 'VIEW - NONE',
 'country': 'US',
 'absenteeInd': 'ABSENTEE(MAIL AND SITUS NOT =)',
 'propclass': 'Industrial',
 'energyType': 'YES',
 'bldgsize': 159183,
 'grosssize': 159182,
 'constructiontype': 'STEEL',
 'bldgsNum': 101,
 'bldgType': 'COMMERCIAL',
 'levels': 1,
 'quality': 'EXCELLENT',
 'storyDesc': 'COMMERCIAL',
 'unitsCount': '144',
 'lastModified': '2021-11-23'}
```